# In which points is $g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, g(z)=|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Hey I have this exercise where I have problems understanding one step of the solution:

we had to check in which points the following function is complex differentiable:

$g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, g(z)=|z|^2=z\bar{z}$

so the solution is $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}=\\ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(z+h)\bar{(z+h)}-z\bar{z}}{h}=\\ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{z\bar{z}+h\bar{z}+z\bar{h}+h\bar{h}-z\bar{z}}{h}=\\ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\bar{z}+\bar{h})+\frac{z\bar{h}}{h}=\bar{z}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} z(\frac{\bar{h}}{h})=\\ \bar{z}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} z(\frac{|h|}{h})^2\overset{*}{=}\\ \bar{z}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} z(\frac{|h|}{|h|\dot e^{i\phi}})^2=\\ \bar{z}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} z e^{-2i\phi}$

I didnt understand the equality (*). Where does the $e^{i\phi}$ come from?

After that we have said that for $z \neq 0$the limit doesnt exist, why?

Comment: Polar coordinates, $\phi$ is the *argument* of the complex number $h$.

Comment: Since $g$ is $C^{1}$, the points where $g$ is complex differentiable are precisely the points where $g$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations. That is just the point $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prof once said "if there is a complex conjugate anywhere, you should look precisely for differentiability".
In your example, the $e^{i\phi}$ comes from switching from $h = x+iy$ to $h = r*e^{i\phi}$.

You have $\frac{abs(h)}{h}$ and you replace this $h = x+iy$ in the denominatore with $h = abs(h)*e^{i\phi}$. Then the $abs(h)$ cancel out and you have $e^{i\phi}$ which is just a complex number with radius 1 on the unit circle.

This means that there is no limit as h approaches infinity.
So, the function is NOT differentiable.